# Promise returns undefined json in Express post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a promise within a selectRecipientData function that returns some user data from an api.

```
export async function selectRecipientData({ email }) {

    engage.selectRecipientData({
        listId: listId,
        email: email,
        returnContactLists: false,

    }, function(err, result) {

        if(err) {
            console.log(err);

        } else {
            let recipient = JSON.stringify(result);

            // this logs successfully
            console.log('Recipient details: ' + recipient );

            return recipient;
        }

    });
}
```

When I call this function within a post request. The data is logged within the promise but is undefined when returned as per below:

```
server.post('/api/v1/public/selectrecipientdata', async (req, res) => {

    formData = req.body;
    let { email } = formData;

    if (!email) {
        res.json({ error: 'Email is required' });
        return;
    }

    try {

        let recipientData = await selectRecipientData({ email });

        // why is this undefined?
        console.log('This is Undefined: '+ JSON.stringify(recipientData) );

        res.json({recipientData});


    } catch (err) {
        res.json({ error: err.message || err.toString() });
    }
});
```

Anyone tell me why? Thanks

Comment: Where does `selectRecipientData` actually return anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've written `selectRecipientData` as a callback style function, but you're calling it as an async/await style. If `engage.selectRecipientData` returns a promise, you could do something like:

```
export async function selectRecipientData({email}) {
    const result=await engage.selectRecipientData({
        listId: listId,
        email: email,
        returnContactLists: false,
    });
    const recipient=JSON.stringify(result);
    console.log('Recipient details: ' + recipient );
    return recipient;
}
```

Otherwise, to convert it to a promise you could do something like:

```
export function selectRecipientData({email}) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        engage.selectRecipientData({
            listId: listId,
            email: email,
            returnContactLists: false,

        }, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } 
            else {
                let recipient = JSON.stringify(result);
                console.log('Recipient details: ' + recipient);
                resolve(recipient);
            }

        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful